# Using paperclip gem in rails3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Using paperclip gem in rails3, there are two copies of image uploaded simultaneously of which one is having null entries and the other is original in the database as I checked in localhost/phpmyadmin. This problem unnecessarily populates my database. Have been searching for quite a few days. Reviewed many answers regarding multiple images but no one mentioned about this problem.

I've followed this code https://github.com/websymphony/Rails3-Paperclip-Uploadify.

Comment: Please provide more information, especially the development.log would be helpful.

Comment: Actually I referred another link fro my application and it works just fine, here's the link you could use http://codeabout.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/gem-paperclip-uploading-files-and-pictures-into-your-rails-application/    Thank you @MoMolog

Comment: Would be best if you could include your code also.

Comment: consider 'upgrading' to carrierwave, it's more maintained and seems to have many more options

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip was also uploading the actual image data into the field image in my database. I had to tweak it to save file names in the image_file_name field in my database.

Here is my controller that saves the image from the upload form.

```
#paperclip replaces spaces with _
formatted_filename = params[:clothe][:image].original_filename
formatted_filename.gsub!(/\s/,'_')

#hook in image processing
#set type of upImg, formUpload (APIUpload, scrapeUpload, mobileUpload)
image = UploadImage.new(formatted_filename, Rails.root.to_s + '/public/products/', @clothe.id)
image.processImage
```

Here is my model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :price, :title, :image, :image_file_name, :published

  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => {
    :thumb => "100x100#",
    :small  => "150x150>",
    :medium => "200x200" },
    :default_url => '/assets/missin.gif',
    :path => Rails.root.to_s + "/public/products/:filename",
    :url => "/products/published/:basename.:extension"
```